# Inserting document with "language" field causes language override not supported

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongo database that uses a text index on one field. For the first time, I'm getting documents that have "language" as a field and this is causing the "language override not supported" error to be thrown when performing an insert. If I remove that field, the document is inserted correctly.

I was wondering if someone has had this issue and found a way to resolve it. Other than checking if that field exists and altering it before insert.

Mongo DB 3.6
Inserting record using PHP:

```
$record = ['projectId' => 40, 'language' => '' ];
$this->dbService->setCollection('subjects');
$this->dbService->insertOne($record);
```

Whether empty or not, the language key causes error. If I exclude it, the record is entered.
Expected behavior: To insert record as given.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added example. It was pretty simple and clear what the issue is.

Comment: It's not clear at all, which is why the question has several close votes on it. What is the "text index" on this collection? Show the details of the index from a `getIndexes()` in the mongo shell. It looks as though you created a "wildcard" index on all fields.

Comment: The index was created using a field. createIndex({'ocr':'text'}). There isn't anything special about the circumstances and it's been working for 4 years with no issues, even after Mongo updates. It's clear I can't have a field called "language" so I'm simply altering it. Go ahead and close the question.

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks for spotting the origin. I just changed the field name to something else